# Stay tuned on or to? Which one is correct?

Tags: grammar, prepositions

I have seen both usages.

1. Stay tuned on our Facebook page to know more
2. Stay tuned to our Facebook page to know more

But don’t know which one is more appropriate. Please help me figure it out. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Objectively speaking, according to Google Books Ngram Viewer, [*stay tuned **to** our*](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=stay+tuned+in+our%2Cstay+tuned+on+our%2Cstay+tuned+to+our&case_insensitive=on&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cstay%20tuned%20to%20our%3B%2Cc0) is the only phrase with any hits when looking at the printed word. (And this is comparing *on*, *to*, and *in*.)

[image: stay tuned to our]

Strangely, despite the results claim that it "yielded only one result," if you click *stay tuned to our* at the bottom of the results page, you'll find multiple instances of the phrase. But there certainly aren't any results when using the other prepositions.

Answer (score 0):

There is also "stay tuned in".

Each of these three is something of an anachronistic idiom, as the "tuned" used to refer literally to the tuning of the radio receiver.  This carried forward easily when television came onto the scene, since TVs originally received broadcasts, like radios do.  With cable TV, webpages, podcasts, and such, literal "tuning" is gone, and the choice of preposition becomes less clear.

I would say that "in" and "to" are more natural to use with "tune", but I would say that "on" is more fitting for something like Facebook.  So I generally wouldn't ask people to "tune" to my Facebook page [1], but if I did, I would encourage them to "tune in" or "tune to".

[1]  Instead, I would encourage them to "return", or "visit", or "subscribe", or "link", or "RSS" if the audience was geeky enough.

Comment: Another way in which "stay tuned" is anachronistic is that, once people had TVs and radios with presets, to change channel/station, you no longer had to *tune* the device -- you could just press a button. One other verb you could use is "watch": "Keep watching our Facebook page..."